# trouble deploying to GCP Functions -GcfJarLauncher class not found

Tags: java, spring-boot, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, microservices

I am trying to deploy a simple Rest API to Google Cloud Functions. Per [this documentation](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-function/reference/html/gcp.html#:%7E:text=The%20function%20target%20should%20always%20be%20set%20to%20org.springframework.cloud.function.adapter.gcp.GcfJarLauncher%3B%20this%20is%20an%20adapter%20class%20which%20acts%20as%20the%20entry%20point%20to%20your%20Spring%20Cloud%20Function%20from%20the%20Google%20Cloud%20Functions%20platform.), I need the target to always be org.springframework.cloud.function.adapter.gcp.GcfJarLauncher

However when I deploy it using the provided code, I get:

```
ERROR: (gcloud.alpha.functions.deploy) OperationError: code=3, message=Build failed: 
build succeeded but did not produce the class "org.springframework.cloud.function.adapter.gcp.GcfJarLauncher" 
specified as the function target: Error: class not found: org.springframework.cloud.function.adapter.gcp.GcfJarLauncher; 
Error ID: d818fd83
```

Here is the code I am running in the Cloud CLI:

```
gcloud alpha functions deploy function-sample-gcp-http --entry-point org.springframework.cloud.function.adapter.gcp.GcfJarLauncher --runtime java11 --trigger-http --source target/deploy --memory 512MB
```

[Here my code repo](https://github.com/AylaWinters/divr-function) but I will include some relevant bits below

pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.5</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.divr-fx-test</groupId>
    <artifactId>divr-function</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <name>divr-function</name>
    <description>Function testing for DIVR</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
        <spring-cloud-function.version>4.0.0-SNAPSHOT</spring-cloud-function.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-function-web</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.8</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-function-web</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.8</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-function-dependencies</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.8</version>
            <type>pom</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>com.google.cloud.functions</groupId>
          <artifactId>functions-framework-api</artifactId>
          <version>1.0.4</version>
          <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-function-adapter-gcp</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.8</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
              <!-- Build an executable JAR -->
              <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
              <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
              <configuration>
                <archive>
                  <manifest>
                    <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                    <classpathPrefix>lib/</classpathPrefix>
                    <mainClass>com.mypackage.MyClass</mainClass>
                  </manifest>
                </archive>
              </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <outputDirectory>target/deploy</outputDirectory>
                </configuration>
                </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.google.cloud.functions</groupId>
                <artifactId>function-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>0.9.1</version>
                <configuration
<functionTarget>org.springframework.cloud.function.adapter.gcp.GcfJarLauncher</functionTarget>
                    <port>8080</port>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Main:

```
package com.fkgcp;

import java.util.function.Function;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;

@SpringBootApplication
public class DivrFunctionApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DivrFunctionApplication.class, args);
    }

    
    // this part I don't actually want to use, but it is present
    // in every tutorial, so I included it to see if it would be 
    // triggered instead of my REST functions
    @Bean 
    public Function<String, String> uppercase() {
        return value -> value.toUpperCase();
    }
}
```

Also, I added a MANIFEST.MF, is it in the right location?

```
divr-function/src/main/resources/META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
```

Contents:

```
Main-Class: com.fkgcp.DivrFunctionApplication
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Can you try this workaround on [github post](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/spring-cloud-gcp/issues/445#issuecomment-823578792)?

Comment: @SarahRemo, Thank you for this. I'm not sure if my company wants to go the Cloud Run route, but I will definitely bring it up. Even if just as a workaround as you are suggesting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reviewing your source code repository, I think the issue can be caused because you need to reference the `spring-cloud-function-adapter-gcp` library as a dependency of the `spring-boot-maven-plugin` in addition to include it as a dependency in your `pom.xml` file:

```xml
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
        <outputDirectory>target/deploy</outputDirectory>
    </configuration>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-function-adapter-gcp</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</plugin>
```

According to the [Spring Cloud documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-function/docs/3.2.8/reference/html/spring-cloud-function.html#_project_dependencies):

> Notice that we also reference `spring-cloud-function-adapter-gcp` as a
> dependency of the `spring-boot-maven-plugin`. This is necessary because it
> modifies the plugin to package your function in the correct JAR format for
> deployment on Google Cloud Functions.

In addition, and although probably unrelated, consider remove your `maven-jar-plugin` configuration from your `pom.xml`: the `spring-boot-maven-plugin` already provides all the necessary functionality to generate the jar you need to deploy and the configuration provided by the `maven-jar-plugin` may be a cause of errors.

On the other hand, your `MANIFEST.MF` file looks fine to me and it is placed in the right location.

Comment: Thank you so much for this! That did work and GCF allowed for the function to be deployed.  Thanks again!

Comment: You are very welcome @AylaWinters. That is nice!! I am very happy to hear that the answer was helpful.